# strange F1 score result using scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing some classification and I was looking at the f1 score and noticed something strange.

When I do:

```
"f1:" + str(f1_score(y_test_bin, target, average="weighted"))
```

I get :

```
f1:0.444444444444
```

When I do:

```
print "f1:" + str(f1_score(y_test_bin, target,pos_label=0, average="weighted"))
```

I get:

```
f1:0.823529411765
```

Which is stange since I set the average to be 'weighted'. This should give me the weighted average of those two scores. Which is independent of the "True label"

I can also see this in the classification report:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.76      0.90      0.82        39
      1       0.60      0.35      0.44        17

avg / total       0.71      0.73      0.71        56
```

In the classification report I get the weighted average, but not when I use the f1 score function. Why is this ?

Comment: I recently asked a similar question: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3122 . The current API is confusing but work is underway to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docstring of `f1_score` contains a paragraph about this behaviour, although somewhat indirectly

```
average : string, [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'samples', 'weighted' (default)]
    If ``None``, the scores for each class are returned. Otherwise,
    unless ``pos_label`` is given in binary classification, this
    determines the type of averaging performed on the data:

[...]

     ``'weighted'``:
        Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average, weighted
        by support (the number of true instances for each label). This
        alters 'macro' to account for label imbalance; it can result in an
        F-score that is not between precision and recall.
```

It says **[...]Otherwise, unless `pos_label` is given in binary classification, [...]**, so *in binary classification* the averaging is overridden and the function just gives back the `f1_score` considering `pos_label` (which is 1 by default) as the detections.

As mentioned in a comment, this special treatment of binary classification has been discussed in a [github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3122). The reason it works this way is mostly due to legacy than anything else: Changing this behaviour may be disruptive to many codebases.

Comment: As a remark, the docstring is even more confusing than I thought, because it sounds as though this behaviour only happens if you actively set `pos_label`, but this is not true: It is **always** the case with binary classification, `pos_label` is considered to be 'given' even if it is only implicitly, by the default value `1`

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem as well and found a solution after reading [eickenberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23919082/2474492) on this thread which is definitely worth a read for the background on this.

In short, sklearn automatically overrides the averaging to take the positive class score when it interprets the data as binary. It does this automatically or when you specify a `pos_label`. The solution then is to redefine the `pos_label` as `None`.

```
print "f1:" + str(f1_score(y_test_bin, target, pos_label=None, average="weighted"))
```

Hope this helps!